# for of loop is only run once

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to traverse a pretty deep object and I need to extract 12 values in different depths. My plan was to extract with the for of the values for each depth but I have a problem in the first depth.

I am a little confused about the for of behavior.
I thought this:

```
   for (const key of Object.keys(jsonData)){
    console.log(i+1);
    if (isWantedValue(key))
    {
        artifactColl[key] = jsonData[key];
    }
    console.log(key, jsonData[key]);
}
```

for of loop would run a cycle for each key element that it finds inside the object but the loop is only running once. It prints out all necessary keys with values in the lower console.log function but it calls isWantedValue function only once.
Can please somebody explain that to me?

Object looks like this:

```
{ searchNGResponse: 
  { totalCount: [ '420' ],
    from: [ '-1' ],
     count: [ '-1' ],
     tooManyResults: [ 'false' ],
     collapsed: [ 'false' ],
     repoDetails: [ [Object] ],
     data: [ [Object] ] } }
```

console output:

```
  1
  called with searchNGResponse
  searchNGResponse { totalCount: [ '416' ],
  from: [ '-1' ],
  count: [ '-1' ],
  tooManyResults: [ 'false' ],
  collapsed: [ 'false' ],
  repoDetails: [ { 'xxx': [Object] } ],
  data: [ { artifact: [Object] } ] }
```

Edit: updated

Comment: Did you forget to post the data and to explain what you want to do, or should we make a wild guess?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure you should have more than one iteraton?

Comment: I want to extract keys and values from a json object and create a new object out of it. Basically having an object without the unnecessary information.
I updated the question with the json object info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsonData` object has only one key, as the console output shows: `searchNGResponse`.

What you want is the keys of that object, the `searchNGResponse` object, specifically `jsonData.searchNGResponse` like this

```
for (const key of Object.keys(jsonData.searchNGResponse)){
    console.log(i+1);
    if (isWantedValue(key))
    {
        artifactColl[key] = jsonData.searchNGResponse[key];
    }
    console.log(key, jsonData.searchNGResponse[key]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good.
I have to look if I can make that with the recursion work or if I specifically grab what I need.
Thanks.